# nohup for loop output naming

Tags: bash, nohup

I use `for` loop to use specific tool with the set of  files:

```
nohup sh -c 'for i in ~/files/*txt; do ID=`echo ${i} | sed 's/^.*\///'`; ./tool $i &&
mv output ${ID}.out; done' &
```

This tool has specific naming for outputted files and I want to rename the output as it would be overwritten and it is simpler for me.
However this specific `mv` doesn't work with `nohup` - files are not renamed individually and get overwritten.

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the complicated `nohup` dance, and not just

```
for i in ~/files/*.txt; do
    ./tool $i && mv output `basename $i`.out
done
```

Comment: I need `nohup` and `&` to run it on the server when I `exit`.

Comment: Have you tried `screen`? It's usually a lot less fragile than trying to `nohup` stuff.

Comment: and why `nohup` and `&` at same time ?